# Unable to check all 3 conditions and return them in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method that checks a `con` variable as `true` or `false` and return a device tag for each device, I could only get the first tag even though the 2nd, 3rd condition is true. How to check all the conditions and return all the devices.

```
 function populateDevices(){

  if(ethsrc[0].con === true) {
    return ethsrc
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          ))
  }
  if(ebmcard[0].con === true){
    return ebmcard
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          ))
  } 
  if(mi5module[0].con === true){
    return mi5module
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you make a `return`, the function stops, everything after won't get executed. You could use a `result` array, concatenate with each array for each condition, like so:

```js
function populateDevices(){
  let result = []
  if(ethsrc[0].con === true) {
   result = result.concat(ehsrc
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          )))
  }
  if(ebmcard[0].con === true){
    result = result.concat( ebmcard
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          )))
  } 
  if(mi5module[0].con === true){
    result = result.concat(mi5module
          .filter(i => i.srcid === 0)
          .map((i,idx) => (
          <Device  name={i.name} srcid={i.srcid} inst={idx} drt={i.drt} data={i.data} />
          )))
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i think this solution is very good but just wanted to add to it is why your code was resulting in a problem. It is happening because of `return` in every `if statement`. When your function is invoked and it checks the `if statement ` which will turn out to be true and will encounter `return` which will prevent further execution of other `if statement`